# What is the transparent part of an envelope called?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the part of a sealable envelope that is made out of transparent plastic and shows the address or a part of what is inside, called?

Comment: You could have got that very simple bit of information from the internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These envelopes are called windowed envelopes so it must be called **the window** of that envelope.